# How to check the HTTP request details that Post Man sent out in Authorization tab

Tags: postman

I am using Post Man to connect to API. The 1st step is to get Token. In the Authorization tab, I fill in the details and click 'Get new Access Token'. Then a small window will show up with a new token in it. Now I want to write a C# program to replicate the procedure to get token. How can I check what has been sent when I clicked the Get New Access Token button? I want to see the HTTPWeb request it sent to the API.

[image: Get token]

[image: Get token resukt]

Answer (score 1):

This is what the console log is for.

It will show all of the HTTP requests by default, including the ones sent by the authorization helpers.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/troubleshooting-api-requests/

You might also want to take a look at the Microsoft Learn docs which explain the OAuth flows for the different grant types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow